# Why is "use" the correct word in the sentence “I hope (…) can be of use”?

Tags: word-choice

I am wondering why "use" is a correct choice in this sentence:

> I hope that my working experience and education can be **of use** to West China Supermarkets.

Instead of "use", Could I use "using" in that sentence? And what is the difference between *use* and *using*?

Answer (score 11):

No, *using* would not fit.

This is the noun *use* (pronounced with an /s/ sound, not a /z/). That has one meaning which is something like *the act of using*, but here it has another meaning which is approximately *usefulness*.

In fact, *of use* is an idiom which means the same as *useful*.

So if you saw

> Use of this equipment is prohibited.

that would be the first meaning, and so *Using this equipment* would be equally good.

But in phrases such as *of use*, *any use*, *no use*, it always has the second meaning: you could substitute *usefulness*, but not *using*.

Comment: +1 though I think the big thing is that "to be of use" is simply a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase). That reason, more than anything else, is why *use* is preferred here. We can still try and justify it, but it's justification in hindsight.

Comment: @ЯegDwight: Since it's also perfectly natural to speak of *wanting to create something of use to others*, for example (it doesn't have to be *something that will **be of use** to others*), I'd be inclined to say it's really just the **of use** bit that's the underlying "set phrase".

Comment: But as I said, it's not just _of use_. That meaning also turns up in _no use_ and _any use_.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the verb **to use** [juːz] with the noun **use** [jus], since they're both spelled the same.

**To be of use** [ʌv ˈjus] means *to be useful*.

She hopes her experience will be useful to the Chinese markets.

Comment: No, they're not, or not necessarily. They may also be thinking of the other meaning of the noun _use_, meaning _act of using_.

Comment: ...which is a noun pronounced [jus] that's all I'm saying. But specifically in the sentence in question, it's undeniably a noun and not a verb.

Comment: Yes it is. But there is no reason to suppose that the OP was thinking of the verb. They might have, but need not have.

Comment: His question and explanation gave me every indication that he was. Perhaps I'm wrong - it's a matter of interpretation I suppose. But does it really matter in the long run? Do you reckon I hurt his feelings. Perhaps I should apologize, or at the very least adopt a policy of applying emotional intelligence before imparting linguistic intelligence. Good God - I have a motto! No, a logo! We'll start a telethon! "Nevergiveup" will be the poster boy. With that name we can't go wrong. WE CAN BEAT THIS! Are you with me?

Answer (score 1):

"Using" wouldn't make sense, but you could replace *of use* with *useful*. "I hope that my working experience and education can be *useful* to West China Supermarkets."